# rails each displaying multiple comments

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have comments in my project and I want to display them in three, and there is a desire to display the remaining comments, too, by three links. how can I render the partial so that he continues to display comments when the button is clicked? help me

posts/_comments.html.haml

```
 .container
  .row.news
   .col-sm-12.news{id: "post-comments-#{post.id}"}
    %h2 Users Comments
  - post.comments.order(:created_at).last(3).each do |comment|
    = render 'posts/comment', comment: comment
.news
  %h5 Add a comment:
  = form_for [post, post.comments.build], remote: true do |f|
    %p
      = f.text_area :text
    %p
      = f.submit
```

posts/_comment.html.haml

```
.row.news-coment
  .col-sm-2
    %img= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url
  .col-sm-5
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-heading
        %strong= link_to("#{comment.user.first_name} #{comment.user.second_name}", user_path(comment.user))
        %span.text-muted #{comment.created_at.strftime('%-d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S')}
     .panel-body
       = comment.text
```

comments/create.js.haml

```
$("#post-comments-#{@post.id}").append("#{escape_javascript render('posts/comment', comment: @comment)}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your post.comment through the form, and add the remote: true option, then you need to tell your controller to respond in js format. I guess it does it, you already created the create js file.

You need to append the created comment, maybe creating a post.comments container, something like:

```
#posts-container
  - post.comments.order(:created_at).last(3).each do |comment|
    = render 'posts/comment', comment: comment
```

And your create.js file is almost ready:

```
$("#post-container").append("#{escape_javascript render('posts/comment', comment: @comment)}");
```

Just make sure to respond in html and js format from your controller method, like:

```
...
  if @comment.save
    format.html { }
    format.js   { }
```

---

In order to load more comments when clicking button then you could try with the following steps.

Create a method in the current controller which allows you to load the next 3 comments depending on the last one. You order the comments depending on their created_at attribute (or whatever you want), ask for those elements which id is minor than the value being passed, and take only 3, like:

```
def load_comments
  @comments = Comment.order(created_at: :desc).where('id < ?', params[:comment_id]).limit(3) 
  respond_to :js
end
```

**Note**: take a look to the difference between `limit` and `take`.

Then, create the GET route in order to respond to your request, like:

```
get 'load_comments', to: 'posts#load_comments' # posts was my controller, your can be anything
```

Then create the `link_to` with the remote: true option which will make the request passing the last `comment.id`, like:

```
<%= link_to 'Load More', load_comments_path(comment_id: @comments.last.id), remote: true, class: 'load-more' %>
```

Note I'm getting the id from the last comment in an ActiveRecordRelationship of @comments, so you need to define it too, in your case maybe in your current controller.

In your view, where's the link_to ready to make a request, you need to set the id from the last comment to make the query, you can do it this way:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('.load-more').href = '/load_comments?comment_id=' + '<%= @comments.last.id %>'
</script>
```

And finally your `load_comments.js.erb` which responds to the method iterates over each `comment` and render it, like:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  $("#comments-table").append('<%= j render "comments/comment", comment: comment %>')
<% end %>
document.querySelector('.load-more').href = '/load_comments?comment_id=' + '<%= @comments.last.id %>'
```

Also sets the last comment's id to make again the request.

My _comment.html.erb file, just looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= comment.text %></td>
  <td><%= comment.post.id %></td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: it's all set up for me. I want to add a button that would output the next 3 comments in the same format. I do not know how to do it

Comment: Can you explain what you really want to do?

Comment: Sorry for my english
I display the last 3 comments and I want to add 3 more comments  on the click of a link or button. I was able to display either all or 3 comments.

Comment: Don't worry, see the updated answer. Is it what you want?